# Unexpected string literal "@hotwired/turbo-rails" in browser console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

## error ...

in the browser console (Safari), it display the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal "@hotwired/turbo-rails". import
> call expects one or two arguments.

This error points to application.js.

Is this yet another rails error than can be safely ignored, is it an indication my set-up is not quite right?  Is it a bug?

## gemfile includes...

```
gem "cssbundling-rails", "~> 1.1"

gem 'turbo-rails'

gem 'importmap-rails'
```

## importmap.rb

```
pin "application", preload: true

pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true

pin "popper", to: 'popper.js', preload: true

pin "bootstrap", to: 'bootstrap.min.js', preload: true

pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true

pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true

pin "trix"

pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.js"

pin "stimulus-autocomplete", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:stimulus-autocomplete@3.0.2/src/autocomplete.js"

pin "choices" # @10.2.0

pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

## application.js

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"

import "popper"

import "bootstrap"

import "controllers"

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "flightrecord",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "7.2.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^7.0.3-1",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^7.0.4",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^7.0.3-1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.2",
    "choices.js": "^10.2.0",
    "currency.js": "^2.0.3",
    "dropzone": "^5.9.2",
    "sass": "^1.56.2",
    "sortablejs": "^1.14.0",
    "stimulus-autocomplete": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
    "tributejs": "^5.1.3",
    "trix": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "19.2.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.19",
    "npm": "6.14.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using import maps to import turbo. Why do you have `package.json`, and why is turbo mentioned there too?

Comment: I installed Bootstrap via a gem and used cssbundler gem to make it work with import maps.  Part of installing the cssbundler gem---creates a package.json file.  I'm not sure if I need it, or should remove it and go another route.